# R Presentation reveal.js: background image not shown after copying file

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, reveal.js

I have authored an R-presentation using rmarkdown and the reveal.js-framework which works perfectly to a large degree, however, if I copy the output-file (the html-file) to another location, all background images are gone. (If I create a copy of the html-file in the same folder it still works). Pictures included using the `<img>`-tag are still shown.

An MWE looks like this:

*presentation.rmd:*

```
---
title: "A Test"
author: "tester"
date: "Today"
output:
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    transition: slide
    theme: night
    highlight: espresso
    center: true
    self_contained: true
    reveal_options:
      slideNumber: true
      previewLinks: true
---

# <font color="black">Outline</font> {data-background="kitten.jpg"}
```

The `kitten.jpg`-file obviously can be any picture. If I open `presentation.html` (using firefox) everything works, if I copy `presentation.html` to the desktop and open it again, all background images are gone.

Any ideas on what is causing the error and how to solve it?

My system is:

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rmarkdown_1.0 revealjs_0.7 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5    htmltools_0.3.5 tools_3.2.3     Rcpp_0.12.7     stringi_1.1.1   stringr_1.1.0  
[7] digest_0.6.10   evaluate_0.9
```

Answer (score 2):

A work-around seems to be to use `{.slide: id="Sec1"}` instead and then adding the background in your custom CSS file

```
#Sec1 {
  background-image: url(kitten.jpg);
}
```

Comment: A promising idea, however, are you sure about your css-code? I don't see any background image. If I change the line to `background-image: url("kitten.jpg");` I see an image (only behind the text though).

Comment: Forgot `url()` ;)

Comment: Looks better, but still, the background image is only behind the text and does not cover the rest.

Comment: Adding these two lines to the css helped for me:
`background-size: cover;` `height: 100%;`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you copy `presentation.html` it is looking for `kitten.jpg` in the same directory are `presentation.html`. When I create Rmd documents, I put all my figures in a `figures` directory, e.g. `figures/kitten.jpg` and when I copy the html file, I also copy the `figures` directory as well.

I'm sure there is a better solution, but this works for me.

Comment: What I wonder though, is that the option `self_contained:` defaults to true. Even if I explicitly state `self_contained: true` things don't change

Comment: `self_contained` seems to work with CSS files and javascript files.

Comment: it also works for images that are included in `img`-tags.